# Insert object to Google Cloud Storage using PHP

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

To be honest, I am really frustrated with the lack of document of Google Cloud Storage with PHP. Most of what I found in here (Stackoverflow) is out of date.

Here is my attempt:

```
$postbody = array('data' => file_get_contents('e.png'));
$gso = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
$gso->setName('testing');
$gso->setContentType('images/png');

$service->objects->insert($bucket_name, $gso, $postbody);
```

The error message

> (400) Upload requests must be sent to /upload/*. Re-send request to the same path, but with an /upload prefix.

From Google Cloud Storage JSON API, I understand that I need to use `upload/storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o` instead of `storage/v1/b/bucket_name/o`, but how do I do it with Google Cloud Storage PHP Client API?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to build a small script that uploads big files to GCS.

[I used Google APIs Client Library for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/installation)

Find it in github https://github.com/guillefd/Backup-manager-gcs

This library manages the file upload (big files) https://github.com/guillefd/Backup-manager-gcs/blob/master/application/libraries/Googlecloudstorage.php

I´m actually using it in many sites and works quite fine.