# Creating a file manager using filestore google cloud php API

Tags: php, google-cloud-filestore

I want to develop a filemanager in my local app using php and I want to use https://cloud.google.com/filestore/  php API for storing files from my website to google cloud filestore but I dont even know how to start where to find php sample script or sdk and how to use that code
I want to create bucket, read , download, delete and add files by using php api , can any one help please and share some sample and where to start

Comment: I recommendation to begin in the doc: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php-storage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert object to Google Cloud Storage using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30600847/insert-object-to-google-cloud-storage-using-php)